# Let $a=2^{2^{35}} +1,b=2^{2^{21}} +1$ , then the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$ is...?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Let $a=2^{2^{35}} +1, b=2^{2^{21}} +1 $. Then $\gcd(a,b)$ is

My little work :

$$a -2 =(2^{2^{22}})^K -1$$
where $K=2^{14}$.

$(2^{2^{22}})^K -1$ is divisible  by$(2^{2^{22}}) -1$
$$\implies a-2= (2^{2^{22}} -1)m ,$$ where $m$ is some integer

$$\implies a-2= ((2^{2^{21}})^2 -1 )m $$

$$\implies a-2=((2^{2^{21}}) -1 )bm $$
Help me to figure out things after this.

Comment: you defined a twice still  ?

Comment: there is still two a

Comment: @Leth Thanks for your careful observation

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Let $p\mid b$. What is $a\pmod p$?

Answer (score 3):

Let $\ c = 2^{\large 2^{\Large 21}}$ so $\ 2^{\large 2^{\Large 35}}\! = (2^{\large 2^{\Large 21}})^{\large 2^{\Large 14}}\! =\, c^{{\large 2^{\Large 14}}}\!.\ $  By one step of the [Euclidean gcd algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/675596/242)

our gcd is $\,(\color{#c00}c^{\large 2^{\Large 14}}\!\!+1,c\!+\!1)\, =\, ((\color{#c00}{-1})^{\large 2^{\large 14}}\!\!+1,c\!+\!1) = (2,c\!+\!1) = 1\,$ by $\,c\!+\!1\,$ odd,

by $\,{\rm mod}\ c\!+\!1\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{c\equiv -1}\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}c^N\equiv (\color{#c00}{-1})^N\ $

**Remark** $\ $ If Euclid's algorithm or mod are unfamiliar you can instead use  divisibility

$$ c\!+\!1\mid c^2\!-\!1\mid c^{2N}\!-1\ \ \ {\rm so} \ \ \ c\!+\!1 \mid (c^{2N}\!-\!1)+2\iff \,c\!+\!1\mid 2$$

---

Or, using orders, if prime $\,p\mid 2^{\large 2^{\Large 35}}\!\!-1\,$ then $\,{\rm mod}\ p\!:\ 2^{\large 2^{\Large 35}}\!\equiv -1\,$ so squaring shows $\,2\,$ has order $\,2^{\large 36}$ by the [Order Test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1188614/242). Hence $\,2^{\large 2^{\Large N}}\!\!\not\equiv 1\,$ for all $\,N < 36,\,$ so $\,p\nmid 2^{\large 2^{\Large N}}\!\!-1.\,$ Generally this argument proves that Fermat numbers with distinct indices are coprime.

Comment: I don't know Euclid ,I am just new with mod can you explain bit more .

Comment: @AakashKumar You don't know  $\,A \equiv a\pmod b\,\Rightarrow\, (A,b) = (a,b),\,$ the reduction step in the Euclid's gcd algorithm?

Comment: No,I don't know this

Comment: @Aakash You can find a [simple proof here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/675596/242) and many other answers. This is a fundamental fact about gcds that you should be sure to know well before attacking gcd problems like this.

Comment: I have tried with another approach , now tell me how to do after this .

Comment: @Akash I added another method. It looks like your edit is going in the same direction of the method I mention in the remark.